# Is there a built-in way to sanitize data with parse_variables?

Tags: parse, xss

I'm a developer on a huge site that does millions of dollars of transactions per day. Our client has recently engaged a White Hat scanning firm to scan the site, and we've been having some issues.

Per their request, we've sanitized all data that's being saved using the `TRUE` parameter on [`input->post`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/input.html). Apparently this scanning company doesn't consider it enough to prevent users from saving bad data; they also insist we sanitize all data before display.

Most of our functions rely on [TMPL->parse_variables](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/template.html#parsing-full-results), so I'm wondering if there's an easy way to sanitize the data in the variable array as well. Or is the only way to call php's `strip_tags` on every variable before it goes into the array?

Comment: I suggest you to contact EllisLab about it. This is an important thing for you and for them.